# catalina.bat start not working

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, nosuchmethoderror

I am having problems starting tomcat for some strange reason, it used to 
start before without a problem.  The error is so long that I can't copy it 
completely from the command prompt. Anyone know what could be going wrong?

```
    C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.8\bin>catalina.bat start

    Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.8"
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.8"
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.8\temp"

    Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23"
    Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.8\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomca
    t-7.0.8\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"



            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
    va:1035)

            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.
    java:291)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic

    e.java:443)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
    java:724)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:25)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:304)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)

    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory examples
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig
    ()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
            at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1281)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav
    a:1276)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
    g.java:874)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
    g.java:317)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
    eSupport.java:119)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
    se.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
    t.java:4974)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
    .java:812)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:78

    7)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
    a:1044)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.j
    ava:967)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472
    )
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1302)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
    :311)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
    eSupport.java:119)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
    se.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:34
    3)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:32
    3)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
    va:1043)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java

    :774)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
    va:1035)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.

    java:291)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
    e.java:443)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
    java:724)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.

    java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:304)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager

    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory host-manager
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig

    ()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
            at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1281)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav

    a:1276)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
    g.java:874)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi

    g.java:317)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
    eSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa

    se.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
    t.java:4974)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
    .java:812)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:78
    7)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)


            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
    a:1044)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.j
    ava:967)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472
    )
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1302)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java

    :311)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
    eSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa

    se.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:34
    3)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:32

    3)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
    va:1043)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
    :774)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
    va:1035)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.

    java:291)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
    e.java:443)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
    java:724)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.

    java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:304)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory manager

    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory manager
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig

    ()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
            at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1281)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav

    a:1276)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
    g.java:874)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi

    g.java:317)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
    eSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa

    se.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
    t.java:4974)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
    .java:812)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:78
    7)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)


            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
    a:1044)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.j
    ava:967)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472
    )
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1302)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java

    :311)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
    eSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa

    se.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:34
    3)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:32

    3)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
    va:1043)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
    :774)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
    va:1035)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.

    java:291)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
    e.java:443)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
    java:724)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.

    java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:304)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT

    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory ROOT
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig

    ()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
            at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1281)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav

    a:1276)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
    g.java:874)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi

    g.java:317)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
    eSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa

    se.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
    t.java:4974)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
    .java:812)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:78
    7)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)


            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
    a:1044)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.j
    ava:967)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472
    )
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1302)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java

    :311)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
    eSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa

    se.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:34
    3)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:32

    3)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
    va:1043)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
    :774)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
    va:1035)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.

    java:291)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
    e.java:443)

            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
    java:724)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.

    java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:304)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]

    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
    12-Apr-2011 8:02:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

    INFO: Server startup in 801 ms
```

Answer (score 11):

```cpp
Error Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()
Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
```

Symptoms: Tomcat cannot start

Probable Causes: This is a new method in `Servlets 3.0` (which `Tomcat 7` supports).
    There is a `Servlets 2.x API` is your `CLASSPATH` or `JDK's` extension directory.
Solution: Check your `CLASSPATH`. Remove `servlet-api.jar` from `JDK's` extension directory if any.

Source: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html

Comment: Hmmm that didn't work. I removed all jars from the classpath, and I cannot find any servlet-api.jar in the jdk folder.

Comment: Well, I have the same error and I have found `servlet-api-2.5.jar` file in my CLASSPATH and removed it. But it didn't help me. And there's no such file in my JDK's extension directory.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this exact error by adding the following jars to my tomcat/lib directory:

javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar

persistence-api-1.0.2.jar

You can find the latest versions here: http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: *Tomcat* shouldn't need you to do that so it can run properly.

Comment: Whether or not it needs some jars is not the issue here. I posted what worked... 15 months ago

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have compiled a jar that includes it's runtime dependencies, and has a reference to an old version of the tomcat servlet-api.jar.

Then when your jar is loaded in a different version of Tomcat, the servlet api is incorrect, and it throws this error.

So check how your jar is compiled and make sure it's not including the servlet-api.jar as a dependency in some way!