# 404 error when accessing tomcat in browser

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

When I'm trying to access `http://myhost:8080/manager/html` It just returns empty page. In file `/var/lib/tomcat7/logs/localhost_access_log.2014-04-16.txt` I can see lines like:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [16/Apr/2014:13:43:53 -0400] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**
Here's what I have found in catalina.out

```
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Apr 16, 2014 3:01:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 16, 2014 3:01:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 610 ms
Apr 16, 2014 3:01:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 16, 2014 3:01:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Apr 16, 2014 3:01:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Apr 16, 2014 3:01:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/manager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1581)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:855)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Apr 16, 2014 3:01:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/manager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1581)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642753/catalina-bat-start-not-working

Comment: Yeah, I have tried the Joe's advice there and it didn't work for me, I still get the same exception.

Comment: Well, it does seem like you borked something in th etomcat installation, as it no longer finds the proper Servlet 3.0 classes - I'd suggest to completely remove tomacat, reinstall, redeploy.

Comment: Hah, reinstallation helped. Thanks.